# Does the Web Deployment Tool installation require a restart on Server 2003/IIS 6?

Tags: iis6, windows-server-2003

I find Microsoft's [Web Deployment Tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/use-the-web-deployment-tool) (and the PowerShell features it enables) very helpful for site management.

Today I'd like to install it on a production Windows Server 2003 / IIS 6.0 server, but I need to know if it might require a reboot or iisreset (in which case I'd have to schedule downtime with change control, you know the drill.) Anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

I was just able to install the current release [Web Deploy 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39277) on an IIS 6/Server 2003 box with no service interruption, so I think I've answered my own question. :)